# Bootstrap questions.. anyone really understand how it works as it seems hard to layout stuff

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

so yeah the title kinda says it all...

Bootstrap hurts my head as it seems impossible to make a form layout that is useful in the real world. Currently I am used the wizards in visual studio to make my forms... but it's impossible to display fields in a different column. Even do some type of format like we have here on this forum.

The picture below is something I would like to do... is this possible... I don't have telrik and I don't understand how to use those controls even If I did had them... but  I saw stuff like that in my search.

[image: Example of What I would like to do..]

I went to the bootstrap site.. well a few sites... one talk about the columns and stuff... the other had downloadable templates that looked nice... but there was not information on how to install them or even use them...

So what's the deal with bootstrap... Is there a site or something that breaks it down in a very simple way so that someone can understand it??

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap's popularity is both their fortune and misfortune. Bootstrap is nothing more, nothing less, than a collection of commonly used elements and components for web development.

Keep in mind they came into being at a time when web development was more hectic and much more basic than today, when there were no stunning themes all over the place and developers had to style websites from top to bottom, including every last detail. And the differences between how each browser rendered them were much bigger than today.

They (Bootstrap) managed to develop a few components people could rely on. Columns that would keep their width and alignment over all browsers, images that would shrink, responsive layouts that would work in all devices and all browsers. If you inspect their solutions, most are ingenious and quite a few are "hacky" but hey, they worked!

Getting back to your question: the real problem with Bootstrap is that quite a few people misuse it, in the sense that, without knowing all of it and without taking the time to actually look at and understand the CSS rules behind it, they just apply classes over classes hoping it would work, cluttering the markup until it becomes unusable.

My advice?
Don't rush it.

When you need a component, start from the very markup Bootstrap provides. Inspect the elements and understand what you need to change in order to make it look/behave like you want. Also, always remember it's ***very popular***. Whenever you want to do something different with a certain element, chances are someone tried it before, perhaps they didn't know how to do it and perhaps they shot a question on SO. And perhaps someone took the time to look at the CSS and do the mod properly.

From my perspective, as it is now, just by searching for high-voted answers on SO and using default examples from Bootstrap, you can solve 95% of anything you might want to achieve with it.

And when you get at the 5% you can't, come here and ask a question on Bootstrap that wasn't asked before. I bet you'll get very good answers and a lot of up-votes.

So you got nothing to lose. Best of luck!